# Problem with restarting Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I have a problem when I'm trying to restart Apache2 on my Ubuntu Server 14.04. I'm getting this error:

```
Restarting web server apache2
[Fri May 23 18:50:56.662042 2014] [alias:warn] 
[pid 8635] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.


[fail]
The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Can somebody help me to fix this error?

Comment: WHY do you not include the command you used? Now someone has to ask: did you start it with or without sudo? and did you look at "The Apache error log" since "... may have more information."

Comment: i typed sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ... thats the command i used for this and get this error ....

Comment: i tried that command but also same error...

Comment: can you please post how you solved the problem? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding **"Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf"** leads to the following error:

> [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3
>   will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.

when restarting Apache.

**Commenting it out again resolves this issue.**

According to this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin adding the include line should not be necessary, at least not in Ubuntu 9.04 (and presumably it also works fine in Ubuntu 12.04).

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04 (comments from Arjan Dasselaar )

You can also try to rename your phpmyadmin.conf for a test.

Comment: OK i commented that i now its not showing that,but still have issue with this:                                         (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80                                             How can i fix that?

Comment: Try this [Apache: Could not bind address to port (make_sock)](http://bocoup.com/weblog/apache-could-not-bind-address-to-port-make_sock/) or this [make_sock: could not bind to address](http://www.who.is.free.fr/wiki/doku.php?id=apache#make_sockcould_not_bind_to_address443)

Comment: Thank you,but I solve this problem and everything is working just fine now .....                                                      Thank you all.